# docker-compse build error - unsupported version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerise my rails app with postgres.  I have followed a few online tutoarials but I'm having a lot of trouble.

I'm also behind a corporate proxy which doesnt help

I can docker docker build --build_args and pass in http proxy.

I'm not trying to run docker-compose build and i get the following error:

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: ‘2’
services:
  web:
    build: .
    context: .
    args:
      - http_proxy
      - https_proxy
      - no_proxy
    command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=abcd12345
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: myappnameapp_development
```

I tried changing the version to 3 and removing it altogether but it always errors.

My second question - do I have to pass in any args when trying to run docker-compose to get through the proxy?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing a version ... I mean that remove the version layer and run the docker-compose.yml

Comment: if I take out version, I get this: Unsupported config option for services: 'web'

Comment: if I take out version and services I get: ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for web: 'depends_on

Comment: `docker-compose up -d --build` --> use this command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are issue is smart quotes in the version value. Use normal double quotes or single quotes

```
version: '2'
```

or

```
version: "2"
```

and NOT `’` or `‘`. They are different from `'` and `"`

**Edit-1**

There are few other issues with your compose, args should be a part of the build. Also args should have a value. They should be used as object and not array. So you correct that as below

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        http_proxy: "192.168.0.11"
        https_proxy: ${HTTPS_PROXY_FROM_ENV}
        no_proxy: ${HTTPS_PROXY_FROM_ENV:-192.168.2.2}
    command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=abcd12345
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: myappnameapp_development
```

So the compose has example how to use environment variables to the pass the value. Also how to use a default value in case the environment variable is not available `${HTTPS_PROXY_FROM_ENV:-192.168.2.2}`

You can also build a specific service and pass their build arguments using below

```
docker-compose build --build-arg "http_proxy=192.168.2.2" web
```

Comment: ok I copied your and got this: ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.web: 'args'

Comment: Let me correct those issue and answer your 2nd part also

Comment: Thanks for this, I copied your in exactly and passed in the build arg with my proxy. Now I'm getting:  ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 11

Comment: Fixed, actually version 3 was needed and I didn't realized the context was also outside build

Comment: Thanks! Working great now! Do you know if I always have to pass in an arg, or can  it pull from my mac $http_proxy?

Comment: If you use `${http_proxy}` for the value of `http_proxy` then it would if shell already has the http_proxy variable defined

Comment: when you say shell, do you mean my mac and not the container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154563/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user3437721).